# Email Background Color issue

Tags: html, css, lotus-notes, html-email, newsletter

I'm creating a newsletter and set the background-color using a hexcode #25292C; When I send the newsletter out the message appears fine. When I forward the newsletter to someone else **the newsletter background overlays the entire email.** I want to prevent the email from getting the newsletter background color. I'm using lotus notes as my email client.

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: No enough info. Are you using inline styles or something different?

Comment: @madhushankarox The newsletter application only allows me to use inline styles

Comment: Isn't that the default/expected behaviour? Why should it change the background color?

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde what?!! Do you get what I'm even asking ?

Comment: @EricOboite in your first version of the question you said `When I forward the newsletter to someone else the email inherits the news letter background color.`. **Inherits**, not **overlays** as you say **after** your edit. So i think my comment was reasonble. Thanks for your polite tone, good luck with your question.

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you are after:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title></head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><!-- << bg color for forwarding // main bg color >> --><table bgcolor="#323232" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:30px;"><tr><td>

<!-- CENTER FLOAT -->
<table width="600" border="0" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding:30px;"><tr><td>

main panel                   

</td></tr></table>
<!-- /CENTER FLOAT -->

</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

When you forward the email to a second recipient, the background is white (or whatever you set it)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
 <body style="background-color:#333333;  min-height:1000px;"  bgcolor="#333333">
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="bg.jpg" color="#333333"/>
      </v:background>
      <![endif]-->
    ......
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using ***Tables***? I have done this and had no issues on FWD emails(well my focus was outlook/gmail/yahoo/aol)

```
<body bgcolor="#25292C">
<div style="background-color:#25292C;"> 
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#25292C">
  <tr>
    <td>
      your stuff
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

...but then again...a lot of email providers (not sure what you focus...Outlook iEX) are not capable of composing (or Forwarding) complex HTML messages in its message body. You can get around this by choosing "Forward as Attachment" or "Redirect" from the Message menu/bar, these will send the message intact (and display inline on some of your recipients' email programs).

Answer (score 1):

Outlook user preferences can strip the body style right out of your email. It is usually a best practice to wrap your content in a  tag and apply colors to EACH  for maximum compatibility with email clients.

It's a pain but it works. Also remember don't use shortened colors like: #F00. Outlook makes these black.

simple email format:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td (width) (bgcolor) (style including font, font-size, color and if applicable, line height)> content </td>
</tr>
</table>
```